# How to show text in in the body of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I wanted to show text from a string variable before the `Wrap` widget. But when I wanted to add something like `Text` before `Wrap` widget it is giving me error. How can show some text before the `Wrap` widget.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Second Route"),
           ),
        body: Center( 
          child:
            Wrap(
              children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
            ),
          )
      );
    }
```

Comment: Can u paste the error here??

Comment: And also perhaps show the _buildButtonsWithNames function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give column as a child to the center widget like this:

```
body: Center(
   child: Column(
       children: [
           Text("Your Text"),
           Wrap(
             children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
           ),
       ],
   ),
),
```

Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to be on top of the `Wrap`, add your `Wrap` to a `Column` and before of it add your `Text` widget.

If you want the text to be just before the `Wrap`, add your `Wrap` to a `Row` widget and do the same as for `Column`.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a way right now!!! from another answer.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("He"),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Wrap(
                children: _buildButtonsWithNames(),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),   
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the column widget and pass the text and wrap widgets as children of the column

Comment: don't comments on answer section...